# Kusto KQL reference first object in an JSON array

Tags: json, azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to grab the value of the first entry in a json array with Kusto KQL in Microsoft Defender ATP.

The data format looks like this (anonymized), and I want the value of "UserName":

```
[{"UserName":"xyz","DomainName":"xyz","Sid":"xyz"}]
```

How do I split or in any other way get the "UserName" value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for the reply, but the proposed solution didn't work for me. However instead I found the following solution:

```
project substring(split(split(LoggedOnUsers,',',0),'"',4),2,9)
```

The output of this is: UserName

Answer (score 2):

In WDATP/MSTAP, for the "LoggedOnUsers" type of arrays, you want "mv-expand" (multi-value expand) in conjunction with "parsejson".

"parsejson" will turn the string into JSON, and mv-expand will expand it into LoggedOnUsers.Username, LoggedOnUsers.DomainName, and LoggedOnUsers.Sid:

```
DeviceInfo 
| mv-expand parsejson(LoggedOnUsers)
| project DeviceName, LoggedOnUsers.UserName, LoggedOnUsers.DomainName
```

Keep in mind that if the packed field has multiple entries (like DeviceNetworkInfo's IPAddresses field often does), the entire row will be expanded once per entry - so a row for a machine with 3 entries in "IPAddresses" will be duplicated 3 times, with each different expansion of IpAddresses:

```
DeviceNetworkInfo 
| where Timestamp > ago(1h)
| mv-expand parsejson(IPAddresses)
| project DeviceName, IPAddresses.IPAddress
```

Comment: This(your approach) is super easy, Thank you very much....

Answer (score 1):

to access the first entry's `UserName` property you can do the following:

```
print d = dynamic([{"UserName":"xyz","DomainName":"xyz","Sid":"xyz"}])
| extend result = d[0].UserName
```

to get the `UserName` for *all* entries, you can use `mv-expand`/`mv-apply`:

```
print d = dynamic([{"UserName":"xyz","DomainName":"xyz","Sid":"xyz"}])
| mv-apply d on (
    project d.UserName
)
```